# how to calculate count in groupBy clause where it includes null/empty fields also

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-sql-2.4.1v, with java8.
I have a use-case scenario where I need to count the total records participated in the group by clause.
i.e. assume i am doing avg with group by.
I also need count of records in that group by.

If I do count(col) as total_count , avg(col) as mean  group by col(year)
this is not considering the filed of col which are empty.
How can I include empty fields of columns in the total_count ?

Answer (score 1):

The groupBy ignores the empty columns. To include these columns, you need to assign values to these empty cells. This can be done using `df.na.fill`. Using this, you can assign a default value to these columns (0 if you want to include them in an average or sum; "some_sample_string" if it's a string type column and so on). After doing na fill, you can apply the groupBy operation to get the desired result.

See the code below:

```
val new_df = df.na.fill(0, Seq("column_list"))
            .na.fill("sample_string", Seq("string_column_list"))
```

Now, you can use the new_df to do your calculations. Hope this helps.